# Check javascript compatibility with Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

I have some javascript code that does not run in IE 11. Is there a quick way to check where the incompatibly is other than going through the code line by line to see what commands and statements are supported by that version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: You can check [this plugin](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat) for eslint to give warnings about browser compatibility for certain methods/syntax/features. **Disclaimer:** I have not used it, so I am not sure how well it works, but on the surface it seems to be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by using [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/) (installed as package on Sublime Text 3) with option "esversion" set to 3 (compatibility with ECMAScript 3).  This got me 90% of the way there and I did the rest manually.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember an "online code checking", but the most similar maybe are this two websites, [can I use?](https://caniuse.com/) and for [Ecmascript](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Hope it helps!